# Squeeze Theorem with a restriction

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

Hi there I have this question:

$$4x - 9 \leq f(x) \leq x^2 - 4x + 7$$

for $x \geq 0.$

Find the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ approaches $4$

I know the answer is seven but why does the question inform me that $x \geq 0$?

Comment: It means that, for $x \geq0$ your function $f(x)$, which you don't know is bounded by those two functions. It, in fact, does not change the calculations, it's just an additional information regarding $f(x)$

Comment: Yes but I don't understand how that information is useful to answering the question.

Comment: Why is this information given?

Comment: Does the additional information help me in anyway or supposed to clear some ambiguity?

Comment: That's what I answered. It's there for tell you about $f(x)$. If you are starting an Engineering course, I'll give you the most important rule for problem solving: YOU DON'T NEED EVERY GIVEN INFO TO SOLVE A PROBLEM.

Comment: You don't need to know it. In fact, the enunciated could have have said: for some $\varepsilon>0$,  $g(x)\leq f(x) \leq h(x)$ for $x \in [4-\varepsilon , 4+ \varepsilon]$ and would have been enough for you to solve it.

Comment: It tells you that in a neighbourhood of $4$ the inequality holds true.  If for eg it said for $x<0$ or for $x\in \mathbb Q$ it holds, you could not have made the conclusion on the limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $x\ge 0$ isn't actually useful or even needed in solving the problem, it's just there to tell you the domain for which $f(x)$ is bounded between those two functions. Because $4$ is in that domain, you can apply the squeeze theorem there.

Answer (score 2):

You don't *really* need to know that $\;x>0\;$ to find the solution, yet as you're working with the function as $\;x\to4\;$ , we can safely assume $\;x>0\;$ ...or, in fact, we could even be happy with only some information for $\;3.9<x<4.1\;$ , say .

I think this is for you to deduce that for $\;x<0\;$ you have no idea at all what happens with the function, whether it is bounded between other two functions or whatever...and you also don't care.